# Count letters after a specific word

Tags: python

I have this response from a server: `HTTP-Version: WEB 981.20\r\n\r\nlogintype=none&since=today`

I know you can count letters by using the function `len()` but this function will count all letters of the response.

How can I count the letters after this phrase: `HTTP-Version: WEB 981.20\r\n\r\n`?

The result should be 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this in a robust manner you need to do several things.

First of all you need to check if the phrase exists in the response and furthermore *where* it exists.

If it does exist, you can then get the length of that part of the response that comes after the phrase.

As follows:

```
response = 'HTTP-Version: WEB 981.20\r\n\r\nlogintype=none&since=today'
phrase = 'HTTP-Version: WEB 981.20\r\n\r\n'

if (offset := response.find(phrase)) >= 0:
    print(len(response[offset+len(phrase):]))
```

**Output:**

```
26
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out this python code:

```
response = "HTTP-Version: WEB 981.20\r\n\r\nlogintype=none&since=today"
substring = response.split("HTTP-Version: WEB 981.20\r\n\r\n")[1]
print(substring)
count=len(substring)
print(count)
```

This code just grabs whatever is after the string you provided and puts it into a substring, then counts it

Comment: How does this achieve the OP's objective of finding the number of characters after the phrase? Why it's the accepted answer is very mysterious

Comment: @DarkKnight I just edited to add a count option, but just using len on the substring would work, which im sure OP figured out

Answer (score -2):

this problem had many solution but this is the easiest one:

```
response = "HTTP-Version: WEB 981.20\r\n\r\nlogintype=none&since=today"
```

and then:

```
part_response = response[-26:]
print(len(part_reponse))
```

Comment: This only works if you know that there are 26 characters after the phrase. You should perhaps re-read the question